# Can I change the weights in a CNN like tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

Can I change the weights in a CNN like tensorflow? Or the weights of the images are fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Tensorflow it is possible, depending on the version and on the layer you use. It is even possible for class weights in the fitting method. Best is you read it in the Documentation for your used Version:-)